# File name expansion in vim when using set option=value

Tags: vim

I'm trying to add an autocmd to vim that will execute whenever I open a file in a certain subdirectory and that sets the search path. Unfortunately path name expansion doesn't seem to work inside a set command.

Specifically I'd like to have a line like this in my vimrc:

```
setlocal path+=**;%:p:h
```

But this will just give me the literal value. Just calling `expand()` doesn't work either. Is there a way to get variable expansion to work here?

Comment: Whitespace is not allowed after the `=` sign in `:set` commands (see `:help :set-args`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
execute 'setlocal path +=**;' . fnameescape(expand('%:p:h'))
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the expansion of the current file's directory; just adding `.` to `path` will do. From the help:

> - To search relative to the directory of the current file, use:
>     `:set path=.`

Comment: You're right of course, but I didn't include in the question that I want to then edit the path I get above (snip off a few directories). So it won't be the directory of the current file.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
let &l:path.=(empty(&l:path)?(''):(',')).'**;'.escape(expand('%:p:h'), ',\*; ')
```

. This is much cleaner then using `:execute 'setlocal path'`, especially knowing that `fnameescape()` was designed to escape paths for commands, not for options and I can say it is not really safe to use it here: it definitely is not going to escape comma and semicolon and add additional escape for space (one for escaping for `:set`, one for the option itself). `(empty(&l:path)?(''):(','))` is here to imitate the behavior of `set+=`.